# How to offset a table column with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to modify value in a table column using it's former value. Currently I use the following two commands:

```
SET @bal = (SELECT balance FROM customers WHERE id = @id) - @amount;
UPDATE customers SET balance = @bal WHERE id = @id;
```

Can I do it in one sentence?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE customers 
SET balance = balance - @amount
WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: Seems obvious, but somehow it did not work for me when I tested it earlier. Probably I made some other mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Dont worry, I have been there doing very complicated things to solve simple things. Having a fresh pair of eyes is always good. :)